# Ethernet controller not recognised - Ubuntu 16.04 - Lenovo Y700-15ISK

Tags: networking, lenovo, ethernet

I have a laptop lenovo Y700-15ISK, with Ubuntu 16.04 and the ethernet controller seems to have gone missing ! 
I have been using ubuntu with a windows 10 dual boot since January without any problems, other than for an unknown reason windows 10 wasn't able to recognize the ethernet cable when plugged. As I don't use a lot windows and as wifi was working great, I didn't try to solve this problem (on ubuntu, everything was fine).

This afternoon, I was on windows for some work and I had to hard-reboot the laptop. I discovered at this moment that it was trying to install some updates.
After rebooting on windows, everything looked normal, but when I came back on ubuntu, it wouldn't recognize the ethernet cable any more !

So here I am. The wifi just work great as usual, but in the network manager, I don't have any "Wired' option any more. I would really much have some help on this problem.

Here is what I tried :

- updating the drivers (reinstalling r8168-dkms)
- resetting BIOS config to default

The command `lspci` give no ethernet controller :

```
 ~$ lspci 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
07:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)
0a:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
```

And `ip link show` give :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 84:ef:18:d5:bf:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I'm afraid I don't know a lot about networks or hardware problems, so any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Maybe update the BIOS? Sounds like a low-level issue.  Also try removing all sources of power (power cable, battery) and hitting the power button a few times.  This sometimes fixes hardware weirdness.

Comment: I can't remove the battery on this laptop... I will try to wear it down a maximum to see if it helps.

Comment: I doubt that would help, but deficiently try updating the BIOS, I was working on one of those once (it had Win10 though) and SuperTuxkart kept crashing until I updated the BIOS, apparently the version those laptops ship with is buggy.

Comment: Actually, just draining the battery completely out of power worked !
I even have ethernet on windows now ! 
I don't really understand what append here but anyway, thanks for your help !

Comment: No problem.  I'll write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a low-level issue.  Try updating the BIOS.   Also try removing all sources of power (power cable, battery) and hitting the power button a few times (in the case of a non-removable battery, drain it as much as possible). This often fixes hardware weirdness.

I was working on one of these laptops once (it had Win10 though) and SuperTuxkart kept crashing until I updated the BIOS, apparently the BIOS version these laptops ship with is buggy.